# Could you reach your top running speed on ice?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction

If you were running on ice, would your top speed be the same as or slower than your top land speed?

Initially, my gut reaction was that you would be able to reach the same speed since static friction means you don't lose energy, and the force to maintain your max velocity shouldn't be that great so even on ice it should be possible to reach your top speed.

Looking for a way to reinforce this with some math, I came across a study about a way to estimate the vertical ground reaction force (hGRF) of the foot based on it's vertical GRF (vGRF) which is used in running studies. It shows that peak hGRF of a stride doesn't coincide with the peak vGRF so now I doubt that there would be enough downward force to maintain static friction, and I have absolutely no clue on how to calculate it.

So then my question becomes: How would you calculate what coefficient of friction is too low to maintain sprint speed with, for a professional athlete, let's say?

Here is the study on estimating hGRF: https://commons.nmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1131&context=isbs

Here is a study on 100-m sprinters containing their hGRF and vGRF at their max speed, although it does not show at what point in their stride they reach max hGRF. based on what I have been reading it seems likely that most studies use the linear hGRF estimate based off vGRF, but this may be helpful none the less: https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00908318/document

Comment: What is hGRF? It seems like you've defined vGRF twice. By the way, neither article you linked ever mentioned the acronym hGRF.

Comment: You need your propulsive force (friction with the ground) to be greater than air resistance if you want your speed to increase. Whether this is the case might depend on what your shoe soles are like (sandpapery vs rubbery?)